# Identifying the data that throws an exception in Python: How to shrink this code?

Tags: python, exception

I have a script that reads in from a file of records that is checking for incorrect data. They might each throw the same exception and they exist on the same line. Is there a way to identify which field threw the exception without having to break it up into multiple lines?

Toy example here:

```
a = [1]
b = [2]
c = [] # Oh no, imagine something happened, like some data entry error
i = 0
try:
    z = a[i] + b[i] + c[i]
except IndexError, e:
    print "Data is missing! %s" % (str(e))
```

The problem is that if there's an exception, the user doesn't know if it's a, b, or c that has data missing.

I suppose I could write it as:

```
def check_data(data, index, message):
    try:
        return data[index]
    except IndexError, e:
        print "%s is missing." % (message)
        raise e

a = [1]
b = [2]
c = []
i = 0

try:
    z = check_data(a, i, "a") + check_data(b, i, "b") + check_data(c, i, "c")
except TypeError, e:
    print "Error! We're done."
```

But that can be pretty tedious.

**What other ways can I use to handle this situation to validate each field in exception blocks, if any exist?**

Example adapted from reality below:

```
class Fork:
    def __init__(self, index, fork_name, fork_goal, fork_success):
        # In reality, we would do stuff here.
        pass


forks = []

# In reality, we'd be reading these in and not all of the entries might exist.
fork_names = ["MatrixSpoon", "Spoon", "Spork"]
fork_goals = ["Bend", "Drink soup", "Drink soup but also spear food"]
fork_success = ["Yes!", "Yes!"]

try:
    for i in range(0, len(fork_names)):
        forks.append(Fork(i + 1, fork_names[i], fork_goals[i], fork_success[i]))
except IndexError, e:
    print "There was a problem reading the forks! %s" % (e)
    print "The field that is missing is: %s" % ("?")
```

Comment: In the situation you've presented, you could avoid error checking every time by simply checking if `len(a) == len(b) and len(b) == len(c)` at the beginning.

Comment: Shove the validation into a function, then call it on each item.  D.R.Y.

Comment: @DanielFairhead I realized that just after writing and edited the post's code to reflect. Still curious if there's any shorter way!

Comment: You should really be using `izip` or `izip_longest` instead of that nasty indexing.  Pre-validation could be as simple as `assert len(set(map(len,(a,b,c)))) == 1` or something more complex, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your error checking into the `Fork` class and use `itertools.izip_longest` to make sure /something/ (really `None`) is passed in if one data stream runs short:

```
class Fork:
    def __init__(self, index, fork_name, fork_goal, fork_success):
        # first, check parameters
        for name, value in (
                ('fork_name', fork_name),
                ('fork_goal', fork_goal),
                ('fork_success', fork_success)
            ):
            if value is None:
                raise ValueError('%s not specified' % name)
        # rest of code

forks = []

# In reality, we'd be reading these in and not all of the entries might exist.
fork_names = ["MatrixSpoon", "Spoon", "Spork"]
fork_goals = ["Bend", "Drink soup", "Drink soup but also spear food"]
fork_success = ["Yes!", "Yes!"]
```

and then change your loop like so:

```
for name, goal, sucess in izip_longest(fork_names, fork_goals, fork_success):
    forks.append(Fork(names, goal, success))
```

Now, you'll get an error clearly detailing which data element was missing.  If your missing element looks more like `''` than nothing, you could change the test in `__init__` from `if value is None` to `if not value`.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch or the exception you still have the information on what caused the 
exception, for example:

```
c_1 = None
try:
    c_1 = c[i]
except IndexError, e:
    print "c is missing."
    raise e # here you still have e and i
```

So you could do something like that:

```
try:
    a = a_1[i]
except IndexError, e:
    raise Exception(e.message+'the violation is because of '+str(i))
```

#### a more complete solution ...

If you are interested in knowing what caused the violation, e.g. which list is two short, you can simply hard code the variables:

```
try:
    for i in range(0, len(fork_names)):
        forks.append(Fork(i + 1, fork_names[i], fork_goals[i], fork_success[i]))
except IndexError, e:
    print "There was a problem reading the forks! %s" % (e)
    print "There are fork_names with size %s " % len(fork_names)
    print "There are fork_goals with size %s " % len(fork_goals)
    print "There are fork_success with size %s " % len(fork_success)
    print "You tried accessing index %d" %  (i+1)
```

OK, I admit seems a lot of work! But it's worth it, because you have to think about your input and expect out put (TDD if you want...). 
But this is still quite lame, what if you don't know how a method called? Sometimes you
will see this:

```
   def some_function(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwrds)
       pass
```

So, you can really hard code the stuff in the exceptions, for this case you can print the stack information, with `sys.exc_info`:

```
try:
    for i in range(0, len(fork_names)):
        forks.append(Fork(i + 1, fork_names[i], fork_goals[i], fork_success[i]))
except IndexError, e:
    type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    for k, v in traceback.tb_frame.f_locals.items():
        if isinstance(k, (list,tuple)):
            print k, " length ", len(k)
        else:
            print k, v
```

The above will output

```
Fork __main__.Fork
traceback <traceback object at 0x7fe51c7ea998>
e list index out of range
__builtins__ <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
__file__ teststo.py
fork_names ['MatrixSpoon', 'Spoon', 'Spork']
value list index out of range
__package__ None
sys <module 'sys' (built-in)>
i 2
fork_success ['Yes!', 'Yes!']
__name__ __main__
forks [<__main__.Fork instance at 0x7fe51c7ea908>, <__main__.Fork instance at 0x7fe51c7ea950>]
fork_goals ['Bend', 'Drink soup', 'Drink soup but also spear food']
type <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
__doc__ None
```

So, after examining the above trace you can figure out which list is too short.  Im admitting, this is like shooting a debugger. So if you want, here is how to shoot a debugger:

```
try:
   some_thing_that_fails()
except Exception:
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace() 
   # if you want a better debugger that supports autocomplete and tab pressing
   # to explore objects you should you use ipdb
   # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

#### final remark:

```
 for i in range(0, len(fork_names))
```

This is not really Pythonic. Instead you could use:

```
 for idx, item enumerate(fork_names):
     forks.append(Fork(idx + 1, fork_names[idx], fork_goals[idx], fork_success[idx]))
```

And like it was said in the comments, `izip` and `izip_longest` are worth looking into.

Comment: It's useful to know that i is still in scope, but what I would like to know is if there's a way to automatically identify which variable has the missing index (ex: 'a') rather than the index itself, without having to encapsulate it all in functions.